# Label background if radio is checked

Tags: css, radio-button

I want to give my upper label a background if the radio button is checked.
I do not want to give the span a background, because the background needs to include the radio button.

```
<label>
   <input type="radio" checked="checked">
   <span>text</span>
</label>
```

See my complete code here: https://jsfiddle.net/kL2h46x5/

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to select the parent of the input element. But you could rearrange your markup to achieve the desired effect:

HTML:

```
<input class="radio-gender bestelling-type" type="radio" checked="checked" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck">
<label class="type-bestelling" for="noCheck">
    <span class="type-bestelling-particulier">Particulier</span>
</label>

<input class="radio-gender bestelling-type" type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck">
<label class="type-bestelling" for="yesCheck">
    <span class="type-bestelling-zakelijk">Zakelijk</span>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
label.type-bestelling {background-color: #f1f1f1; margin-right:10px;}

input:checked+label {
    background:red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kL2h46x5/9/

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/kL2h46x5/6/

Use

```
 :checked + span {
      background-color: #f10;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want a entire background. Also the radio button included. Thats why I want to give the label a background.

Comment: Ah, you wrote label so I assumed the span. One sec please.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kL2h46x5/8/ I can't whole thing to change background color, sorry. Someone else will have to help, if it's possibile at all.